# Calculating/obtaining a "centerpoint" inside a multipolygon entity with FME software?

Tags: fme-form, centroids, multipart, multi-polygon, fme-transformer

Obviously, this point does not necessarily have to be the real centroid, but it does have to be a, only one, single interior point of each multipolygon.

[image]

What I have found is the CenterPointReplacer transformer, but having a multipolygon as origin the result is wrong.
[image]

I have worked with other softwares like ESRI, which can do this task, but now I need to process this result using FME software, I have not found the way to do it.

ORIGIN: MULTIPOLYGON

FINAL: POINT

Comment: Try adding a nearest transformer and then using the xy coordinates in a geometry replacer

Comment: Does FME support PointOnSurface like http://postgis.net/docs/ST_PointOnSurface.html?

Comment: There's no PointOnSurface transformer...

Comment: Could you consider to use GDAL instead of FME, or is is important to do everything with one ETL tool?

Comment: The CenterPointReplacer https://www.safe.com/transformers/center-point-replacer/ has on option `somewhere guaranteed to be inside the feature's area`. Have you tried that?

Comment: Yes i do, but when you are playing with multipolygons... it does not work... and puts a point outside of everywhere...

Comment: Yes it's important,... I could do that with other software like arcgis, but i need it with FME.

Comment: Which version of FME are you using? When I try it in 2021.1 with the CenterPointReplacer mode set to "Any Inside Point" then it works fine with multipolygons.

Answer (score 2):

[image: CenterPointReplacer Parameters]

I went back as far as FME 2019.0 and indeed the CenterPointReplacer does work with MultiPolygons (as it should) in the way you desire AS LONG AS you set the Mode to Any Inside Point.  Hope that helps.